# In an unsorted array, replace every element by the first larger element to the right

Tags: arrays, algorithm, data-structures, time-complexity

In an unsorted array, we have to replace every element by the first element to the right that is larger than the current element.  If none of the elements to the right are bigger then it should be replaced with `-1`.

Example:

```
3  1  2  5  9  4  8   should be converted to
5  2  5  9 -1  8 -1
```

I can think of the trivial solution where we check every element with the entire array which is an *Ο(n²)* solution. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: shouldn't it be -1 2 5 9 -1 8 -1?

Comment: @lakesh: As far as I understand, 5 is the first value larger than 3 that is to the right of the first position

Comment: @NiklasB. oh ok.understood the question wrongly.

Comment: Note that the trivial algorithm is only `O(n^2)` in the worst case. It should be `O(n)` on average.

Comment: @nwellnhof: Really? How is that? It's not immediately obvious to me

Comment: Are all the elements 1 digit integers?

Comment: @nwellnhof : How did you arrive at O(n) time for average case? Can you explain a bit more?

Comment: @DeanMacGregor : No, elements can be any integers

Comment: I guess unbounded positive integers, since -1 is a marker for "not found"

Comment: @NiklasB. In the average case, you'll find the first element which is larger with probability 0.5 in the next position, with probability 0.25 in the second position, etc. So the expected value of elements to inspect is SUM(k * 0.5^k | k > 0) which equals 2.

Comment: @nwellnhof: This assumes that all elements have the same rank inside the array (n/2), which can't be true. We would rather need to sum over all possible ranks, something like `sum_{i=1}^n sum_{k=0}^oo (i/n)^k = sum_{i=1}^n (n / (n - i)) = Ω(n log n)`. Still pretty good though

Comment: If we have non-distinct elements it gets much worse though

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The main idea is to process the array in reverse order (from right to left). We make a few observations:

- If we are currently processing index *i*, *k > j > i* and `A[k] ≤ A[j]`, then we call element *k* irrelevant, because it will never be the result for any of the elements *1, 2, ..., k*
- The relevant elements right of an index *i* therefore form a monotonically strictly increasing subsequence of `A[i+1..n-1]`.

In your example, the sequences of relevant elements would be from right to left:

```
       []    
      [8]
    [4,8]
      [9]
    [5,9]
  [2,5,9]
  [1,5,9]
```

It looks like a stack, and we can indeed use a stack to maintain this sequence between iterations.

When processing a new element, we first need to find the result for the array element. The observation is that the result is the topmost element on the stack that is *not* invalidated by the new element. Therefore we can just pop from the stack all elements that have become irrelevant. What is then on the top is our result. We can then push the new element because it is relevant by our definition.

```py
stack = []
A = [3, 1, 2, 5, 9, 4, 8]
result = [-1]*len(A)
for i := len(A) - 1 to 0:
    # remove all elements made irrelevant by A[i]
    while not stack.empty() && stack.top() <= A[i]:
        stack.pop()
    # now the top of the stack is the result for index i
    if not stack.empty():
        R[i] = stack.top()
    # push the new element on the stack. The stack will still contain all relevant 
    # elements in increasing order from top to bottom
    stack.push(A[i])
```

The loop invariant for iteration `i` is "*`stack` contains the subsequence of relevant elements to the right of index `i`*". It is easy to verify and implies the correctness of this algorithm.

Every element is pushed and popped at most once, so we have a total runtime of *Ο(n)*.

Comment: I think you mean `A[k] ≤ A[j]`. Also, I think your code would be more readable if you put the bodies of `if` and `while` on a line on their own. Apart from details: +1

Comment: Can whoever downvoted give a reason? N.B.: I have no relation to the author of this answer

Comment: @WalterTross: Yes you're right, changed that. I also added some syntax highlighting :)

Comment: Exactly same algorithm as me except right to left process. you could have said this as a comment in my post. This is not fair.

Comment: @Trying: First of all, conceptionally it's pretty much a different thing and a bit easier to implement. Secondly, I tried to add an actual explanation and justification of why this works, as well as why it has the intended runtime. I feel that it adds to the purpose in multiple ways. Also you can't claim ownership of the idea behind this, since it's pretty obvious, as commented by others as well

Comment: You can use array with binary search for speedy look-up.

Comment: @Deep speedier than amortized O(1)? ;) seriously though, binary search doesn't help here because you need to remove elements as well, which requires the same work as doing a linear search

Comment: Well, removing elements is not really "work", its just assigning a value to the stack pointer. You shouldn't be constrained to using a standard `pop()` operation. Anyway, don't forget to count comparisons, when stating the O (although I wouldn't know how to express the result concisely)

Comment: @WalterTross: You're right, you can speed up the algorithm. It will still be linear time though, so it's better to keep it simple and don't try constant optimizations. In practice it will probably make close to no difference, since binary search might be less cache efficient, cause branch mispredications etc etc. The number of comparisons is also asymptotically the same in the worst and average case (`O(n)`)

Answer (score 3):

you can use a stack and the time complexity is **`O(N)`**.

**`algo:`**
Start from the left side and move towards right. When you pick an element form the array (lets say x) pop the stack till the elements from stack (lets say y ) has element greater than the array element i.e. x> y. Than push the element i.e. x to stack.

e.g.  `{40,50,11,32,55,68,75}` . here `s` is stack.

40, as s is empty push it. `s: 40`

50, as s.peek() < 50 so pop 40 (40's greater element is 50) than push 50. `s: 50`

> Next higher element of 40 - 50.

11, s.peek() > 11 so push 11. `s: 50, 11`

32, s.peek() < 32, so pop the element and now it's 50 which is greater than 32 hence push 32. `s: 50 ,32`

> Next higher element of 11 - 32.

55, s.peek() < 55, so pop the element i.e. 32 than pop next as well as 50 < 55, than push 55. `s: 55`.

> Next higher element of 32 - 55.
>
> Next higher element of 50 - 55.

68, s.peek() < 68 so pop it and push 68. `s: 68`

75, s.peek() < 75 so pop it and push 75 `s:75`.

> Next higher element of 68 - 75.

As the array does not have any element no just pop the stack say that for all the elements inside the array does not have greater element i.e. -1.

> Next higher element of 75 - -1.

**The same algo in code:**

```
public static void fun(int[] a) {
    Stack<Integer> s = new Stack<Integer>();
    s.push(a[0]);

    for (int i = 1; i < a.length; i++) {
        if (s.peek() != null) {
            while (true) {
                if (s.peek() == null || s.peek() > a[i]) {
                    break;
                }
                System.out.println(s.pop() + ":" + a[i]);
            }
        }
        s.push(a[i]);
    }
    while (s.peek() != null) {
        System.out.println(s.pop() + ":" + -1);
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you do with the non `-1` elements? How do you find the next larger value?

Comment: I don't think you've thought this through enough.  Can you give (even very rough) pseudocode for this algorithm?

Comment: I also don't think this works. You need to maintain the whole monotonically increasing subsequence while iterating from left to right, since the result for a position could be anywhere in the middle from that subsequence

Comment: @Trying: Your code crashes on my computer because you `peek` an empty stack. After fixing that, it doesn't work on OP's example

Comment: Although I think your approach is correct. It can indeed work in `O(n)`. Your implementation is wrong, however

Comment: @Trying: Your Java code still doesn't work at all. `peek` can only be called on a non-empty stack.

Comment: Although your implementation has minor mistakes, but algorithm is correct. As soon as I looked at the question I was thinking Niklas B's method, did not think loop from left to right will work too !

Comment: please comment why negative voting. Thanks.

Comment: Didn't downvote, but I guess it's because your Java example doesn't work