# Monotonic Pair - Codility

Tags: java, algorithm

I was just at Codility, and ran into a task for which I can't find a solution in targeted O(n) efficiency; my solution runs for O(n2). I would be very pleased if someone could just give me a hint on how to get it run faster. Here is the task.

A non-empty zero-indexed array A consisting of N integers is given.

A monotonic_pair is a pair of integers (P, Q), such that 0 ≤ P ≤ Q < N and A[P] ≤ A[Q].

The goal is to find the monotonic_pair whose indices are the furthest apart. More precisely, we should maximize the value Q − P. It is sufficient to find only the distance.

For example, consider array A such that:

```
A[0] = 5
A[1] = 3
A[2] = 6
A[3] = 3
A[4] = 4
A[5] = 2
```

There are eleven monotonic_pairs: (0,0), (0, 2), (1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (2, 2), (3, 3), (3, 4), (4, 4), (5, 5). The biggest distance is 3, in the pair (1, 4).

Write a function:

class Solution { public int solution(int[] A); }

that, given a non-empty zero-indexed array A of N integers, returns the biggest distance within any of the monotonic_pairs.

For example, given:

```
A[0] = 5
A[1] = 3
A[2] = 6
A[3] = 3
A[4] = 4
A[5] = 2
```

the function should return 3, as explained above.

Assume that:

N is an integer within the range [1..300,000];
each element of array A is an integer within the range [−1,000,000,000..1,000,000,000].
Complexity:

expected worst-case time complexity is O(N);
expected worst-case space complexity is O(N), beyond input storage (not counting the storage required for input arguments).
Elements of input arrays can be modified.

And my 1st idea solution (runs in O(n2)):

```
    public static int solution(int[] A) {
    int max = 0;
    for(int i=0; i<A.length-1; i++) {
        for(int j=i+1; j<A.length; j++) {
            if(A[j] >= A[i] &&
                    (j - i) >= max) {
                max = j - i;
            }
        }
    }
    return max;
}
```

Comment: The same idea can be used that is described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22233018/in-an-unsorted-array-replace-every-element-by-the-first-larger-element-to-the-r/22234440#22234440

Comment: Also the same algorithm :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a temporary array containing maximum values in descending order:

```
int[] top = new int[A.length];
int max = -Integer.MAX_VALUE;
for (int i=A.length-1; i>=0; i--) {
    if (A[i] > max) max = A[i];
    top[i] = max;
}
```

so you can quickly find them with binary search:

```
int find(int[] t, int min) {
    int s = 0;
    int e = t.length-1;

    if (t[e] >= min) return e;

    while (true) {
        int x = (s+e) / 2;
        if (x == t.length-1) return t.length-1;
        if (t[x] >= min && t[x+1] < min) return x;

        if (t[x] < min) e = x;
        else s = x;
    }
}
```

And you got a solution:

```
int best = 0;
for (int i=0; i<A.length; i++) {
    int c = find(top, A[i]) - i;
    if (c > best) best = c;
    if (best >= A.length-i) return best;
}

return best;
```

Answer (score 7):

MarcinLe's is better than n^2, but still runs in nlogn. You can optimize by not doing your logn lookup every time. Instead, iterate forward over your max array and your input A[] array at the same time to guarantee linear time.

```
int[] top = new int[A.length];
int max = -Integer.MAX_VALUE;
for (int i=A.length-1; i>=0; i--) {
    if (A[i] > max) max = A[i];
    top[i] = max;
}

int best = 0;
int curMaxIndex = 0;
for (int i=0; i<A.length; i++) {
    while(curMaxIndex < top.length && top[curMaxIndex] >= A[i])
        curMaxIndex++;
    if((curMaxIndex - 1 - i) > best)
        best = curMaxIndex - 1 - i
}

return best;
```

Answer (score 1):

There is also another algorithm, based on finding maximum distance between pairs (sorry, PHP), it also has O(n2) complexity:

```
function solution($a) {

    $length = count($a);

    for($max = $length-1; $max > 0; $max-- ) {
        for($i = 0; $i < $length - $max ; $i++) {
            if ($a[$i] <= $a[$i+$max]) {
                return $max;
            }    
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to think in terms of distance. It is like the breadth first search. Look for all the couple that have the max distance ( being the size of the array ) then the ones with distance - 1 and so on. I am working on it and will try to come with a c++ solution.

Comment: This is sometimes fast, but n^2 in the worst case.  Think what would happen on [5,4,3,2,1].  It would look at every possible combo before returning length 1.

Answer (score 0):

I came across the similar test and chose to resolve it in C.
I believe my solution runs as O(nlog(n)) worst case and O(1) best case.
Now I use O(1) loosely, but it's very possible.

Basically I worked with 2 pointers. One moving slowly from tail of the array, and one scanning against each found from the head.  I immediately break from the loop on the pairs whose indices are the furthest apart which happen to be the ones calculated first using this method.

O(1) becomes possible because if the first monotonic pair you calculate happens to be at the end and head of the list, then that is your answer.  There is no possible value larger then this to return.

```
int solution(int A[], int N) {
    // write your code in C90
    int p,q;
    // forward and backwards iterators
    int fi,bi=N-1;
    // track largest difference
    int diff=0;

    // interate through entire loop
    for(; bi >= 0; --bi){
       // Initialization
       p=q=bi;
       fi=0;

       // looking from the front
       for(fi=0; fi<bi; fi++){
          if(A[fi] <= A[p] && A[q] >= A[fi] && fi<bi){
             p=fi;
             break;
          }
       }
       if(diff < (q-p)){
          diff = (q-p);
       }

       if(diff >= bi){
          break;
       }
    }
    return diff;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My Solution But got 66%. Its O(n**2) time complexity. Code is in JavaScript.

```
function solution(A) {
    var N = A.length;
    var distance = 0;
    for(var i = 0; i < N-1; i++) {
        for(var j = i; j < N; j++){            
            if(A[i] <= A[j]  && (j - i) > distance)
                distance = j - i;
        }
    }
    return distance;
}
```